# Why multiplicative 1 is equal to the integer 1?

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently reading W. Rudin's Principles of Mathematical  Analysis (3d ed.)

There is the following theorem 1.20(a):

> If $x \in $ $\mathbb{R}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x>0$, then there is a positive integer $n$ s.t. $nx>y$.

The proof provided by the author asumes that $m+1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ for any $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and that $x*1=1$

From the previous text, I understood that we are guarantied that there is an object $u \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $u*x=x$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field.

But how do we know that $u=1$? (here 1 is our "usual", integer 1)

Edit: There was no explicit construction of $\mathbb{Z}$ shown previously in the text. However, there was this theorem 1.19:

> There exists an ordered field $\mathbb{R}$ which has the least upper bound property.
>   Moreover, $\mathbb{R}$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subfield.

Maybe I don't know something about "$\mathbb{Q}$ being a subfield" part?

Comment: How are the integers defined?

Comment: How are your integers defined? How is multiplication in the integers defined? How are your real numbers defined? How is multiplication in your real numbers defined? How is multiplying an integer with a real number defined? Answering these five questions should lead you closer to an answer.

Comment: @Arthur I'm assuming OP is using Rudin's definitions.

Comment: @Don Thousand, you are correct

Comment: @DonThousand I don't know what those are. Also, I was trying to nudge the OP into thinking about these definitions, as that's likely the first step to an answer.

Comment: @Arthur Von Neumann definition of naturals, and integers are the smallest superset of the naturals which is a group under addition. But yes, I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb Q$ is a subfield, presumably the identity of this subfield is the integer $1$, and a subfield has the same multiplicative identity as the field containing it. This is because for a field element $a$ if there is any nonzero element $b$ such that $ab=b$ then $a$ is the identity.

Comment: Your answer is what I was afraid of. I see the part where "if 1 is the identity element of a subfield then it must be the identity element of the entire field". Where can I read on why "1 is the identity element in Q"? Because I can't see it from the previous text of the book.

Comment: @George You can calculate that $1x=x$ for any rational $x$, no special deduction is required other than that to decide that it is the identity.

Comment: Oh... Indeed... This is what I find one of the most difficult parts of studying "hard" mathematics. Not only don't I know what I do not know, but I even don't know what I do know. Thank you very much.

Comment: @George No problem.